# Determine the most appropriate install location using the $PATH variable

Tags: c, linux, makefile, environment-variables

How can I from the $PATH variable determine in my Makefile which is the most appropriate install location for my program so that normal users can execute the program? Or any other method, since all system are different there can't exactly be a static value in each makefile.

For me, first value is /usr/sbin - probably not prefered over /usr/local/bin?

Answer (score 4):

Don't guess. You'll get it wrong.

Use `/usr/local` and let the user override it at `make install` time.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Variables for standard `GNU Make` variables to use for this.

Comment: I thought there were some way to determine which of all those paths  that is better used, depending on the system. If installed on BSD or Ubuntu, maybe the "preferable" paths are different.

Comment: `/usr/local` *is* the preferred path on linux historically, BSD uses `/opt/local` for ports I'm not sure if that's also for self-compiled or if that is still `/usr/local`. I suppose the `LSB` might say something about this but I'm not aware of it offhand. But as I said, you cannot guess. The most appropriate location for a library might not be in `$PATH`. The user might be trying to use `stow` or app-paths. Just don't.

Comment: `/usr/bin` is usually populated by the vendor's software management, e.g. a Linux distribution's package manager - you don't want to interfere with that. This is why `/usr/local/...` is a good default. It is also what everybody else uses.